# SVG Fill Exclude

Tags: css, svg, reset, fill

I am playing with userstyles.org, customising CSS (I'm a hack) to get a desired effect.

**I want to fill all SVG's with a colour, but exclude some SVG's from being affected by the fill.**

Assuming I have a *data-icon* called *image*, how can I exclude this or reset its attributes?

I have the following: Sorry no HTML in this example.

```css
 /* set colour vars */
 :root { 
    --bgi: #B4B4B4; /* icon colour */
    --bgf: #B4B4B4; /* icon fix */
 }
 
 /* colour icons */
 span svg path {
    fill: var(--bgi); 
    }
    
/* fix misc icons */
 span[data-icon="link"] svg path 
 {
    fill: var(--bgf) !important; 
}

/* exclude icons */
span[data-icon="image"] svg path 
 {
fill: none !important; 
}
```

"*fill: none*" just makes the SVG transparent.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused about your full requirements but I think you should be coloring (filling) all the icons that are NOT`[data-icon="image"]`

So..

```
span:not([data-icon="image"]) svg path {
    fill: var(--bgi); 
    }
```

...should work

> The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.
>
> <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)</sup>

Comment: You're on the right track, but that doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a specificity issue.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with nesting? i.e. the SPAN is nested under a BUTTON, LI, UL, DIV, DIV, SPAN etc

Comment: Probably, you would have to check what rules are actually applying and override them.